# Rail displaying only models whose parent model belong to the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a Rails 5 app and have run into an issue where my Projects model index shows projects for all users on the platform.

The way my app is structured is that I have a Project model which belongs to a Vehicle model which belongs to a user. When I go to my Projects index, all the projects from other users also show. How would I get only projects that their parent Vehicle model have the User id for the current user? Or would it be better to also add a user id to the Project Class.

Here is my Project controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.where(completed: 'false')
  end

  def all_projects
    @projects = Project.all
    render :index
  end

  def finished_projects
    @projects = Project.where(completed: 'true')
    render :index
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    @back_url = session[:my_previous_url]
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new(vehicle_id: params[:vehicle_id])
    @vehicles = Vehicle.where(user: current_user)
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    @vehicles = Vehicle.where(user: current_user)
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :details, :vehicle_id, :completed)
    end
end
```

I am using devise for authentication if that makes any difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add some joins and a where condition to match the current user. Some alternatives.

no users join

```
@projects = Project.joins(:vehicle).
    where(vehicles: {user: current_user})
```

with user join

```
@projects = Project.joins(vehicle: :user).
    where(users: {id: current_user.id})
```